# Is there a way to automatically remove all unused properties in a Angular project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a large Angular project, and I believe there are a lot of unused properties declared in .component.ts.

Is there a way to automatically remove all unused properties in a Angular project that also considers if the property is used in the template.component.html ?

Comment: Why would it matter? Are you worried about size of the produced javascript file or code cleanup or something else? Also if it is just one component why not clean it up manually?

Comment: Try using `ng lint`. It will point many syntax errors and anti-patterns. Also will point unused variables, imports and property. `ng lint --fix` should fix many of it, but not unused variables/property

Comment: WebStorm will show unused properties for a component both by functions, methods or Angular templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS Code

`Shift+Alt+O` will take care of you.

Comment: This runs over all project? Does it consider a Angular project, where you can use a declared property just in the html template?

Comment: it works over all project. whatever variables unused will show up

Comment: This seems to organize imports only

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> optimises imports in webstorm.

Comment: Properties aren't imports.